How can I log a filepath, which was initialised using boost::filesystem::path?
In my cpp code, I set the following variable outfilepath:
auto outfilepath = boost::filesystem::path{workdir} / output_filename;

During runtime I would like to see what this looks like, so I try:
logger::stdout->warn("The outputfilepath looks like {}", outfilepath);

However this throws an error during the build:
    /home//js/build/_deps/spdlog-src/include/spdlog/fmt/bundled/core.h:1757:7: error: static assertion failed: Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#udt
 1757 |       formattable,

Any ideas how I can log it properly? Thanks in advance!

A side note: why do you use boost instead of std::filesystem::path (available since C++17) ?

@wohlstad I wasn't aware of that - I can use that instead :)
